# NetLogo: select neighboring patches to a patch-set

Tags: netlogo

I'm modeling home range selection in NetLogo. I'd like a turtle to identify the subset of patches that are neighbors to its current home range. The turtle should then identify which neighboring patch is best (defined for now as the patch with highest food benefit) and move to that patch to claim it. It continues these steps (identify available patches neighboring the home range, select best option, add to homerange, repeat) until it has enough food within the home range.

Part of the code is as follows, but I get the error that "FACE expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead." I think something is off with the reporter or my use of it (I'm new to reporters; I'm trying to make the code modular to minimize procedure length).

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
patches-own [
  owner
  benefit 
  used?
  ]

to-report edge-patches-of [my-homerange]  ;; reporter to find patches along edge of homerange
  report my-homerange with [
    any? neighbors with [
      owner = [owner] of myself
    ]
   with [used? = false]  ;; (only want neighboring patches not already owned)
  ]
end

to pick-homerange
         ifelse food < food-needed  ;; (turtle builds homerange until it has enough food)
          [ let my-homerange patches with [owner = myself]
            ask edge-patches-of my-homerange [set pcolor red ]  ;; (this to just see the options)

            ;; now that we know the options, pick the best: 
            let available-destinations edge-patches-of my-homerange   
            set destination max-one-of available-destinations [([benefit] of patches)]
             face destination
              forward 1
              if patch-here = destination
               [ add-destination ]  
           ]
         [stop] 
end
```

Comment: This error means that there are no patches that suit the conditions of your reporter. That doesn't necessarily mean your reporter is not working- a turtle may just be out of patches onto which it can expand from its current homerange. You can start troubleshooting by adding an if-statement so that your `face destination` block only runs if the reported "destination" is not nobody (something like
`if destination != nobody [`
`face destination ... etc ]` ). That should help figure out if your reporter is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You have not included enough code or description to be sure, but it seems that your logic is overcomplicated and contains conceptual errors.  Try this as a starting point.  Note in particular the test for a nonempty set of candidate edge patches.

```
globals [food-needed]
patches-own [owner capacity]
turtles-own [homerange]

to setup ;make sure all turtles have an initial homerange
  ca
  ask patches [set owner nobody]
  crt 10 [
    set-initial-ownership
    ;do the following just once, not over and over
    set homerange (patches with [owner = myself])
  ]
  ;etc
end

to-report benefit [_t] ;patch proc
  ;patch reports benefit to turtle _t
  report 1 ;or whatever
end

to-report food ;turtle proc
  report sum [capacity] of homerange
end

to pick-homerange ;turtle proc
  ;; (turtle builds homerange until it has enough food)
  if (food >= food-needed) [stop]
  let _candidates edge-patches
  if any? _candidates [  ;you almost certainly need to add this
    let _destination max-one-of _candidates [benefit myself]
    face _destination forward 1
    if (patch-here = _destination) [augment-homerange _destination]
  ]
end

to augment-homerange [_p] ;turtle proc
  ask _p [set owner myself]
  ;just add to the homerange as needed; don't keep recreating it
  set homerange (patch-set homerange _p)
end

to-report edge-patches ;turtle proc
  ;; (only want neighboring patches not already owned)
  report (patch-set [neighbors] of homerange) with [owner = nobody]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm very new to NetLogo. Could you explain the kind of conceptual errors are you seeing? Also, I've tried modifying my code following your advice and still get a destination of "0" so nothing happens--the turtle does not pick a homerange. I'm totally confused. I can't figure out why it won't set a destination from one of the edge-patches. Any further advice?

Comment: That is a different error than before.  It sounds like you still have destination as a turtle attribute and that you are using that before assigning a patch to it.  That is not the case in the code I posted, where `_destination` is a local variable.  (The code you posted did not produce a persistent turtle destination, so I did not include one.)

Comment: Okay, yes, destination was a turtle attribute and I see there probably is no reason to have that. Now it's a local variable. I'm excited because this mostly works now, but for one new thing. The turtle will occasionally "hang" between two patches over and over. I.e., it won't reach the destination, but bounces between two random patches. Any idea what could cause this? And is there a way to have the turtle show its current _destination so I could see if that's part of the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @User847462 http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers 
Also, new questions should be asked as a new question, not as a comment.  However, I will guess that the destination patch is changing each move, which presumably will trace to how you are computing the benefit.  Make sure that the benefit of a patch does not decline as the turtle approaches it.